# How to remove authors names and affiliations for a double-blind review process?

Tags: latex, review, sharelatex

How to remove authors names and affiliations for a double-blind review process?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the author's section using this line of code:

```
%\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Removed for blind review}}
```

Comment: Depending on which documentclass and packages you use, you might also want to check if any identifying information is stored in the pdf meta data